# Can a .sh file be a dependency in a makefile?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, makefile

I am using bash on Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to create a README.md file using a makefile wherein guessinggame.sh is the dependency. The README.md file created is fine. But each time I run make, the README.md file is recreated even if the dependency has not changed. Earlier I've used .txt files as dependencies and they have worked fine. Could someone tell me what am I missing here?

Following are my codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File: guessinggame.sh

no_files_guessed=0
no_files_actual=0
difference=0

# Function to prompt the user for next guess
function next_guess {
    echo "Guess again:"
    read no_files_guessed
}

# 1. Count the number of files in the current directory
#    Excluding: Directories and Hidden files
no_files_actual=$(ls -p|grep -v '/$'|wc -l)

# 2. Ask the user to guess the number of files in the curret directory
echo "Guess the number of files in this directory and then press [ENTER]: "

# 3. Prompt the user for a guess
read no_files_guessed

# 4. Give user a clue to guess the correct no. if the initial guess is incorrect
while [[ $no_files_guessed -ne $no_files_actual ]]
do
    difference=$no_files_actual-$no_files_guessed
    if [[ $difference -le 10 ]] && [[ $difference -gt 0 ]]
    then
        echo "Your guess is low."
    elif [[ $difference -ge -10 ]] && [[ $difference -lt 0 ]]
    then
        echo "Your guess is high."
    elif [[ $difference -gt 10 ]]
    then
        echo "Your guess is too low."
    elif [[ $difference -lt -10 ]]
    then
        echo "Your guess is too high."
    fi
    next_guess
done

# 5. Congratulate the user for guessing the correct number
if [[ $no_files_guessed -eq $no_files_actual ]]
then
    echo "CONGRATULATIONS !!! Your guess is correct"
fi
```

makefile:

```
all: README.txt

README.txt: guessinggame.sh
    echo "#GUESSING GAME#" > README.md
    echo >> README.md
    echo "*Time Stamp at which make was run:*" >> README.md
    date >> README.md
    echo >> README.md
    echo "Lines of code in guessinggame.sh:" >> README.md
    wc -l guessinggame.sh|egrep -o '[0-9]+' >> README.md

clean:
    rm README.md
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nothing to do with `.sh` files, which can be used as a dependency just like any other file, nothing special going on there.

The bug is simply: the `Makefile` recipe claims to create `README.txt`, but it actually creates a file named `README.md`. So the next time `make` is run, it sees that `README.txt` still doesn't exist, and runs the recipe again.

To protect against future such errors, use `$@` instead of `README.md`; it will expand to the name of the target file.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas especially for $@ tip.